# Microsoft.Web.Administration and Removing IIS Apps Iteratively

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am using C# with Microsoft.Web.Administration to remove all of the apps inside of a site. I do not want to remove the site app itself (path = "/").

Here's the code:

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
for (int i = 0; i < manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.Count; i++)
{
    if (manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[i].Path != "/")
    {
        manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
manager.CommitChanges();
```

What happens with this code is that some apps get removed and others don't, and which apps get removed and which don't are different each run.

```
manager.Sites[sitename].Applications.Clear();
```

will work, but it will also remove the application with path = "/", which I don't want.

I tried doing something like this, too:

```
Application baseApp = null;
for (int i = 0; i < manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.Count; i++)
{
    if (manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[i].Path == "/")
    {
        baseApp = manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[i];
    }
}

manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.Clear();

if (baseApp != null)
{
    manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.Add(baseApp);
}

manager.CommitChanges();
```

But that didn't work either. The app with path = "/" was never re-added, or wasn't added properly.

Is there anyone with more experience with Microsoft.Web.Automation who has some insights on removing more than one app at a time that can help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was making the classic stupid mistake of altering the collection while enumerating through it. The first app would be removed and the count would go down. Some apps were never getting looked at. The randomness of the removal was simply due to the unordered nature of the collection. Silly me!

This works:

```
     List<Application> appsToRemove = new List<Application>();
     for (int i = 0; i < manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.Count; i++)
     {
        if (manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[i].Path != "/")
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Removing {0}", manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[i].Path);
           appsToRemove.Add(manager.Sites[siteName].Applications[i]);
        }
     }
     foreach (Application a in appsToRemove)
     {
        manager.Sites[siteName].Applications.Remove(a);
     }
     manager.CommitChanges();
```